# NSNumberFormatter numberFromString returns null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

Here's my code

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [currencyStyle setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [currencyStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    NSNumber *amount = [[NSNumber alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"the price string is %@", price);

    amount = [currencyStyle numberFromString:price];

    NSLog(@"The converted number is %@",[currencyStyle numberFromString:price]);
    NSLog(@"The NSNumber is %@", amount);

    NSLog(@"The formatted version is %@", [currencyStyle stringFromNumber:amount]);

    NSLog(@"--------------------");
    self.priceLabel.text = [currencyStyle stringFromNumber:amount]; 

    [amount release];
    [currencyStyle release];
```

This is what the log spits out

the price string is 5
The converted number is (null)
The NSNumber is (null)
The formatted version is (null)

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Updated code

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyStyle setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [currencyStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    NSNumber *amount = [currencyStyle numberFromString:price];

    NSLog(@"the price string is %@", price);
    NSLog(@"The converted number is %@",[currencyStyle numberFromString:price]);
    NSLog(@"The NSNumber is %@", amount);
    NSLog(@"The formatted version is %@", [currencyStyle stringFromNumber:amount]);
    NSLog(@"--------------------");

    self.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", [currencyStyle stringFromNumber:amount]]; 

    [currencyStyle release];
```

Comment: Should work if price is defined similar to this: `NSString *price = @"5";`. Also do not allocate and init `amount` since you later assign it to an autoreleased value, and also do not release amount.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is `price`? Assuming it's an ivar, do not access ivars directly. Always use accessors except in `dealloc` and `init`.

Assuming `price` is a string, why are you doing this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", price]
```

If `price` is an `NSNumber`, then you can use it directly.

You're creating an `NSNumber` here, assigning it to `amount`, and then immediately throwing it away. You then over-release `amount`. So you should expect the above code to crash. (Because of a quirk in how `NSNumber` objects are managed, this crash will happen the next time you create an `NSNumber` for the integer 5.)

And getting all the way around to your actual question, the reason amount is `nil` is because "5" is not in the current currency format, so the number formatter rejected it. If you are in the US and set `price` to "$5.00" then it would work.

---

If you're really trying to convert a string to US$, then this is how to do it. Note that locale matters here. If you use the default locale, then in France "1.25" will be €1.25, which is not the same as $1.25.

You should always us `NSDecimalNumber` when holding currancy. Otherwise you're subject to binary/decimal rounding errors.

The following uses ARC.

```
NSString *amountString = @"5.25";
NSDecimalNumber *amountNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:amountString];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

NSNumberFormatter *currencyStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];    
[currencyStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyStyle setLocale:locale];
NSString *currency = [currencyStyle stringFromNumber:amountNumber];

NSLog(@"%@", currency);
```

A more complete class for managing localized currency (`RNMoney`) is available in the example code for chapter 13 of [iOS 5 Programming Pushing the Limits](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1119961327,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html).

Comment: Wow... so all I had to do was format the price string to include a $ at the beginning and it works fine... My whole goal in the code was to convert a string (example 1.25) into a currency ($1.25) is there a better way to do this?