# NSNumber being returned as null when formatted using NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have a text field that I want to take in values as an NSNumber, but when the data goes into a table view it is returned as null. Here's the code I have:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber *numberPrice = [numberFormatter numberFromString: self.itemPriceTextField.text];
self.listItem.itemPrice = numberPrice;
self.listItem.itemDesc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", numberPrice];
```

There are no currency symbols in the text field just input from the user with regular whole numbers (ex: 12, 52, or 35)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What's the text inside `self.itemPriceTextField.text`?

Comment: All numbers, I restricted the keyboard to the numpad

Comment: Does the text have a currency symbol?  Did you set the currencyCode?  Did you try NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8402132/335858

Comment: What is the actual value of the text that you're trying to convert??  Without that info this question is meaningless and deserves to be downvoted and closed.

Comment: There are no currency symbols in the text field just input from the user with regular whole numbers (ex: 12, 52, or 35).

Comment: @HotLicks: Please keep in mind that new users ought to be welcomed and assisted in their first posts.

Comment: @Stefan - Please keep in mind that anyone coding in Objective-C should already know the basics of debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the number style `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` then your input is expected to have a currency symbol.  Try using  `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` for numbers without the currency symbol .

Comment: Thanks, Mike! For some reason I thought the currency style would automatically add the .00 after whole numbers